# Java/Swing app Freezes randomly

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtable, swingworker

I have a simple Swing button that refreshes a jtable, but after a random number of clicks the application freezes, sometimes indefinitely, sometimes it responds after a minute or so. I never did any thread especific method so I think maybe that`s the issue but I don`t know where to start or how to modify the methods if that is the cause of the freezes.

This is the code:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    recorrerLista();
}  


public EventList recorrerLista(){
    Persistir p = Persistir.getInstancia();
    Vector<Pedidos> lista2 = p.listarPedidos();
    Iterator it = lista2.iterator();
    if(!pedList.isEmpty()){
        pedList.clear();
    }
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v = (Vector) it.next();
        int index = (Integer)v.get(0);
        Pedidos ped = new Pedidos();
        ped = p.buscarPedidoPorId(index);
        pedList.add(ped);
    }
    return pedList;

}
```

**Edit: I tried inserting the method of the persistence class (Persistir) inside a SwingWorker but now the UI don't show up.**

Here is the code

```
public Vector listarPedidos() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException{
SwingWorker listar = new SwingWorker<Vector, Vector>(){

    @Override
    protected Vector doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Vector<Articulos> lista = null;
  EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidosPU" );
  EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
  em.getTransaction().begin();

  try {
    Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM pedidosview WHERE ENTREGADO='P' ORDER BY fecha_pedido");

lista = (Vector) query.getResultList();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
    em.getTransaction().rollback();
  } finally {
    em.close();
    emf.close();
  }
    return lista;
        }
  
 };
    return (Vector) listar.get();

}
```

## **Edit 2: I did what was suggested and i get a null pointer exception, here is my code:**

```
public Vector listarPedidos(){
//Vector<Articulos> lista = null;
final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidosPU" );
final EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

final SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker(){  
  private Vector lista;
  

  @Override
  protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
      em.getTransaction().begin();

    try {
      Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM pedidosview WHERE ENTREGADO='P' ORDER BY fecha_pedido");

      lista = (Vector) query.getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
      em.getTransaction().rollback();
    } finally {
      em.close();
      emf.close();
    }
      return lista;
    }


 };
   worker.execute();
   return lista;


}
```

## Edit 3: I added this code to the `ActionPerformed()` of the button. But it seems to skip the code entirely

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    final Persistir p = Persistir.getInstancia();
    

    SwingWorker<Void, Pedidos> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Pedidos>() {
        //private Vector lista2;
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistir.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidosPU" );
            EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

            String jqpl = "SELECT * FROM pedidosview WHERE ENTREGADO='P' ORDER BY fecha_pedido";
            //TypedQuery<Articulos> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Articulos.class);
            Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM pedidosview WHERE ENTREGADO='P' ORDER BY fecha_pedido");
            //query.setParameter("param", "P");

            //lista = (Vector) query.getResultList();
            List<Pedidos> lista2 = query.getResultList();

            publish((Pedidos[])lista2.toArray());

            em.close();
            emf.close();
            return null;
        }

@Override
protected void process(List<Pedidos> chunks) {
    Iterator it = lista2.iterator();
            if(!pedList.isEmpty()){
            pedList.clear();
            }
            while(it.hasNext()){
            Vector v = new Vector();
            v = (Vector) it.next();
            int index = (Integer)v.get(0);
            Pedidos ped = new Pedidos();
            ped = p.buscarPedidoPorId(index);
            pedList.add(ped);
            }
}

@Override
protected void done() {
    jButton1.setEnabled(true);
}    
    };

worker.execute();
}
```

Comment: _" Do I need to modify it so it runs on the same thread of the GUI?"_ - May be the other way around where you need to run it on a _different_ thread. You seem to be already running on the ui thread (EDT). Long running tasks should be run on a background thread. Your `Persistir` class is hitting the db, which is probably causing the ui to be unresponsive. So yes, you'll probably want to run that on a `Swing Worker`. See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Comment: Have a look at some of the [swing-swingworker-jtable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jtable+swingworker+swing) tagged questions for some ideas also.

Comment: In addition to wise @peeskillet comments, on heavy update processes it is a common practice to disable the button till update be done, in order to avoid users trigger the same action repeatedly.

Comment: I tried inserting the method inside a SwingWorker but the UI don't show up now. Obviously i'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) implementation is pretty much like if you don't have nothing at all, because at the end of `listarPedidos()` you call [get()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#get--) method:

```
public Vector listarPedidos() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ...
    return (Vector) listar.get();
}
```

Thus causing the [Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) get blocked until [doInBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground--) is complete:

[image]

You should use [publish()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) and [process()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process%28java.util.List%29) instead. Since you use JPA, I'm assuming that you can manage to get an Entity called `Articulos`, so you could do something like this:

```
SwingWorker<Void, Articulos> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Articulos>() {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PedidosPU" );
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        String jqpl = "SELECT a FROM Articulos a WHERE a.entregado = :param";
        TypedQuery<Articulos> query = em.createQuery(jpql, Articulos.class);
        query.setParameter("param", "P");

        List<Articulos> resultList = query.getResultList();

        publish((Articulos[])resultList.toArray());

        em.close();
        emf.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Articulos> chunks) {
        // add your items to the table model here
        // this code runs in the EDT
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        refreshButton.setEnabled(true);
    }    
};

worker.execute();
```

---

#### Off-topic

Given the use of [Vector](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) classm I suspect your table model is [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) (if this is not the case pelase disregard this off-topic comment), which is not the best ally to work with complex model classes.

If this is the case (and given the fact you seem to speak Spanish), please see [this post (in Spanish)](http://javaparasereshumanos.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/creando-un-tablemodel-reutilizable-en-swing-parte-i/) *(or [in English](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?&tl=en&u=https://javaparasereshumanos.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/creando-un-tablemodel-reutilizable-en-swing-parte-i/), courtesy of google translate)* about creating a reusable table model using domain classes. If you don't speak Spanish, you still could look at the `GenericDomainTableModel` class code posted at the end of [this entry](http://javaparasereshumanos.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/creando-un-tablemodel-reutilizable-en-swing-parte-ii/) *(or [in English](https://translate.google.co.uk/translate?&tl=en&u=https://javaparasereshumanos.wordpress.com/2014/08/02/creando-un-tablemodel-reutilizable-en-swing-parte-ii/))* because, well, it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: I have a question. I did what you suggested and I get a null pointer exception. Let me clarify a little, the method listarPedidos returns a Vector of said objects, when i set a breakpoint to debug i see that the code inside the Swingworker is totally skipped. and since i need a return of Vector i need the method to give me said vector but it is empty. I don't know why the code is skipped or why i can't get my vector.

Comment: Hi there. You need your Vector to populate your table model, right? That's what this SwingWorker does asynchronously: get the List of `Articulos` in `doInBackground()` method and use `publish()` method to process that list and update your table model within `process()` method to warranty that will be done in the EDT. You `listarPedidos()` doesn't have to return nothing just because you get the list and process it all together in the same step. @IsmaelMarquez

Comment: I don't know why when i use a breakpoint in the `actionPerformed()` of the button at runtime it skips completely whats inside `SwingWorker`, it goes directly to `worker.execute()`and it does nothing. Why is that and why am i doing wrong?

Comment: I forgot to mention that i'm using GlazedLists to populate the table and show the changes when the List updates